# File_Get_Contents not displaying picture in localhost

Tags: php

I've tried using:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo file_get_contents("www.example.com/img.jpg")
```

and:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo file_get_contents_curl("www.example.com/img.jpg");
```

and both methods give me the same broken image with the url pointed to:

```
http://localhost/01_Tests/filegettest.php
```

What's the issue?  I have the allow_url_fopen = on as well.

**edit var dump:**

```
<html>
<body>
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font       color='#cc0000'>'ÿØÿà&#0;JFIF&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;ÿÛ&#0;„&#0;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#10;  &#10;   &#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&#10;&#10;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;&#13;ÿÀ&#0;&#0; &#0;È&#0;ÿÄ&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0; &#10;ÿÄ&#0;H&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;!1&quot;AQ2aq#BR‘   3Sr’“¡±ÁÑÒáðñCTb‚”$%4DcƒÓÿÄ&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0; ÿÄ&#0;=&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;!&quot;1A2QRa‘Bq#Sb’¡ÁÑr‚¢±ðáñ$3ÿÚ&#0;&#0;&#0;?&#0;ò«À„`B0!ŒF#À„`B0!ŒF#À„`B0!ŒF#F#À„`B0!ŒF#À„`B-À„`B0!ŒF#À„`B0!~…ß&quot;¤ÿ&#0;MGÿ&#0;ZàÅç'...</font> <i>(length=13088)</i>
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `http://www.example.com/img.jpg`? `www.example.com/img.jpg` is a relative path on the local file system, not a URL.

Comment: This is _all your code_? You don't have any other output in there, including whitespace before/after `<?php ?>`?

Comment: please post the result of **var_dump(file_get_contents_curl("www.example.com/img.jpg"));**

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sorry, I just omitted that for brevity but that's pretty much the code aside from <?php ?>

Comment: @ceejayoz yep, I have the http:// in there as well.  It still doesn't work

Comment: @sbaaaang the var_dump doesn't show anything for me.  It's the same page with a broken image that's pointed to http://localhost/01_Tests/filegettest.php

Comment: @yay4programming if it doesn't shows anything it means your are printing something that doesn't exists, so be sure about the file and the url for the file

Comment: assuming you have curl enable tho

Comment: did you tryed **var_dump(file_get_contents(www.example.com/img.jpg));** ?? you have to debug deeply man :) and you'll get the fix by yourself for sure :)

Comment: The problem with @sbaaaang `var_dump`'s code is because of your header. When debugging you should try to use `Content-Type: text/plain` or `text/html`.

Comment: Thanks @h2ooooooo I've updated original post with the var_dump

Comment: @yay4programming That's your problem. You want to output an image (`image/jpeg`), but you're getting HTML (xdebug's `var_dump` - outputted from `img.jpg`)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I think it was because I was outputting HTML so I could post the var_dump.  Otherwise, it will just output nothing with it.. this issue is driving me nuts, I can't figure out why it's doing this.

Comment: nevermind i figured it out.  Thanks @h2ooooooo

Comment: @yay4programming Don't *ever* just write "nevermind I figured it out" or the next person having the same problem will not be able to find a solution either. Always explain what you've done to fix the problem so  others can be helped as well.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Good point.  What happened was I was processing the picture in php in between <HTML> tags.  Once I got rid of the <HTML> tags, it all worked out.. now I'm trying to figure out how to display the picture in an HTML script..